# DirectSound8 has different behavior on windows 7 vs windows 10 wrt headphones plugged in

Tags: windows, audio, directsound

On a windows 10, with no headphones plugged in:

```
DirectSoundCreate8 returns S_OK
IDirectSoundBuffer8::Play returns 0x8889000F (potentially AUDCLNT_E_ENDPOINT_CREATE_FAILED)
```

and this is the first call to return any error.

On a windows 7, with no headphones plugged in:

```
DirectSoundCreate8 returns DSERR_NODRIVER;
```

The problem is, if the Play() call is the first call to return that anything is amiss, I have to have already loaded and decoded a sound (expensive) just to figure that I can't play sounds...

This seems crazy so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you provide some code indicating what format & flags you are using? Does your system have no sound device at creation?

Comment: Note also that DIrectSound is legacy. Have you looked at [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction)?

Comment: This code plays WAVE_FORMAT_PCM buffers with all sorts of sizing params.  The context is a video game, so includes source files decoded from oggs, voice chat over network packets decoded via opus,  as well as simple wav files as source. The flag is 0 or DSBPLAY_LOOPING. Every sound fails with that error with played. The first sound, the game's music failing, is the one I've looked at most. This code has existed for 15 years and shipped numerous products, and works in the 99% other cases so  I'm not super interested in throwing it all out and starting over just to fix this one issue ;)

Comment: What return value do you get in these two cases when you call ``SetCooperativeLevel`` right after the create? Also are you using ``DSDEVID_DefaultPlayback`` or ``DSDEVID_DefaultVoicePlayback`` as the default device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior difference here is that Windows 10 / Windows 11 is using [Virtual Audio Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/virtual-audio-devices) for WASAPI, while Windows 7 version of WASAPI does not support virtual audio devices.

The reason virtual audio devices were introduced is because WASAPI end-points come and go as the speakers/headphones are plugged and unplugged. WASAPI clients had to handle this scenario by destroying and reattaching to end-points. For XAudio2 API users, this was surfaced as an 'on-critical-error' that required games to destroy and re-create their audio graphs as sound devices were physically removed. With the new virtualized behavior, WASAPI moves the end-points around automatically.

> XAudio2 clients can opt-out of this behavior by using `XAUDIO2_NO_VIRTUAL_AUDIO_CLIENT` when using XAudio 2.9 either as part of the Windows 10 / Windows 11 OS or when using [XAudio2Redist](http://aka.ms/XAudio2Redist) on Windows 7 SP1 or later.

DirectSound has had various levels of emulation since Windows Vista, and its behavior is mostly tuned for appcompat with existing titles. This list of limitations for DirectSound has been true since Windows Vista:

- `LOC_HARDWARE` buffers are unsupported.
- Surround-sound (beyond stereo) buffers are supported as `LOC_SOFTWARE` (on Windows XP, these had to be `LOC_HARDWARE`).
- Effects (I3DL, EAX, etc.) are not supported through DirectSound.
- DirectSound 3D audio continues to support only mono channel sounds, while XAudio2 supports multi-channel 3D audio.
- Appcompat shim are applied in some cases to redirect the 'default' device from `DSDEVID_DefaultPlayback` to `DSDEVID_DefaultVoicePlayback` (or `DSDEVID_DefaultCapture` -> `DSDEVID_DefaultVoiceCapture` for capture).

I'm not aware of any 'opt-out' flag for the virtualized audio device for DirectSound, but if you enumerate an audio device via `DirectSoundEnumerate` and use that GUID instead of the default device, it will likely bypass it.

> The latest version of the DirectSound samples from the legacy DirectX SDK are on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-legacy-samples/tree/main/DirectSound). They build with modern Visual C++, and *do not* make use of the legacy DirectX SDK. The DirectSound samples do require the Visual C++ MFC optional component to be installed.